# How to define write preferences without tag sets?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

considering a replica set composed of 5 members :

- R1,R2,R3,R4 being replicas
- A1 being an arbiter

I would like to ensure my application handles a write preference during replication.
For example, with writeConcern w:2 I want the replication/write to occur on R1(Primary of course) and R3(Secondary), but if R3 goes down the replication process can use any other secondary.

Using tag set to handle this case is not satisfying, if R3 goes down the write will fail.

Is there any write preferences available in mongodb I could use ?

Notes : (R1,R2) are in one datacenter, (R3,R4) in another one, A1 is in a third one.

Thanks.
BR.

Comment: I don't think there's a reasonable way to do this besides perhaps Markus's suggestion, which only persists until connections close or mongod's restart. It seems like what you really want is [multi-datacenter write concern](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-replica-set-tag-sets/#custom-multi-datacenter-write-concerns).

Comment: Setting writeconcern with tags or setting w:3 is a problem when a DC  or enough hosts fail (write blocked or fail on timeout). It seems mongodb is able to handle writeconcern but not write preferences, write preferences could help to have  more resilient solutions to outages than write concern from application POV.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to use something which is called "replication chaining". It basically works like this:

1. You create (or reconfigure) your replica set with [chaining allowed](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#local.system.replset.settings.chainingAllowed)
2. You tell R2 and R4 to replicate from R3 using [replSetSyncFrom](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-replica-set-secondary-sync-target/).
3. Done!

The syncing should look like this after following these steps:

```
R1
 └── R3
      ├── R2
      └── R4
```

The good: If R3 fails, R2 and R4 will revert to sync from R1.

The bad: When R3 is up again, you have to tell R2 and R4 to sync from R3 again.

The ugly: When you restart R2 or R4, you have to tell the instance to sync from R3 again.

However, this setup should basically give you what you want without creating a single point of failure.

Comment: I can't apply this solution, (R1,R2) and (R3,R4) are in different datacenters, so using such topology will increase bandwidth between dc.

Comment: Which you should have written in the question. This scenario might be solvable using tag based _ sharding_. Please add _ all_ constraints to your question.